# PHP Upload with file type and size check

Tags: php, html, upload

I need a upload form which other people can use, to hand me in their documents.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
<table>
<tr><td><p>your name:</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="name" type="text" size="50" style="height: 30px;"></td></tr>
<tr><td><p>your mail-adress:</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><input name="mail" type="text" size="50" style="height: 30px;"></td></tr>
<tr><td><p>your document:</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="file" name="file" value="" /><br /><h6 style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 2px;">max. filesize: 2 MB<br />allowed filetypes: .doc, .docx, .pdf, .rtf, .odt</h6></td></tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$fehler = "";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$file = $_POST['file'];
$maxsize = "2097152";   /* 2MB in Bytes */
$allowedext =  array('doc','docx' ,'pdf', 'rtf', 'odt');

  if (empty($name)) {
   $fehler .= "<p>&bull; no name given!</p>" ;
  }
  if (empty($mail)) {
   $error .= "<p>&bull; no e-mail adress given</p>" ;
  }
  if (empty($file)) {
   $error .= "<p>&bull; choose a file!</p>" ;
  }
  if (empty($error)) {
   if (!in_array(filetype($file), $allowedext) { /* check filetype */
   $error .= "<p>&bull; filetype is not allowed</p>" ;
}
if (empty($error)) {
   if (filesize($file) > $maxsize) { /* check filesize */
    $error .= "<p>&bull; file is too big</p>" ;
   }
   if (empty($error)) {
    /* send data via mail */
    echo("your document has been send.");
   }
  }
}
echo($error);
echo ('<p><a href="../send_article">back</a></p>');
?>
```

I want to check the file type and the size before uploading it. When I upload the upload.php file to my server i just get a white screen without any errors, if i try to use this form.

Comment: Validating the file type _before_ the upload is pretty difficult. You could try checking the file name extension, as you started to implement, but that does not really make sense since this certainly is _not_ a file type validation. Also the php approach you show certainly does not validate before the upload, but after. Why do you want to do that validation _before_ the upload? Why not in the server side?

Comment: About the error: no need _guess_ here what the error _might me_. Take a look into your http servers error log file, that is where it says what the problem is.

Comment: @arkascha. Never mind, however you can check the file-type. See my answer, but there is a caveat however.

Comment: @Mouser Then could you explain how that checks the file type?

Comment: @arkascha `file-type` returns a mime-type. Create a list of mime-types for the files allowed and cross-reference them.

Comment: @Mouser Hm, read a bit, that actually looks quote promising. I always assumed the `type` attribute only reflects the name extension, but now I see it considers some magic number catalog. As said: promising. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer provides the solution to check size before uploading to data to the server. This makes sense. If you do a client check, you can eliminate unnecessary posts to your server. A sanity check on the server remains necessary, JavaScript code on the client can be altered. The other answers provide explanation on how to improve your server side code.

```
var mimeTypes = [
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", //docx
    "application/pdf", //pdf
    "application/msword", //doc
    "rtf;application/rtf", //rtf
    "rtf;application/x-rtf",
    "rtf;text/richtext",
    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text" //odt
    ]

function readFiles(files)
{
    var iMax = files.length;
    var sum = "";
    var max = 2097152;
    for (var i = 0; i < iMax; i++) 
    {
        var fileType = files[i].type;
        var fileSize = files[i].size;
        sum += parseInt(fileSize);

        if (mimeTypes.indexOf(files[i].type) == -1)
        {   
            alert("Invalid file selected");
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (sum > max)
    {
        alert("Total file size exceeds maximum upload size.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
document.getElementById("form").querySelector("input[type='file']").addEventListener("change", readFiles, false);
```

`readFiles` fires whenever a *change event* is fired on the file input. In browsers supporting *HTML5 input elements* you can read out the `file type` and `file size` property. They are inherited from the `Blob` object. You can even pass the file to a *FileReader* object allowing you to read the contents of the file.

> Bug in IE 10, 11. On IE10 and 11 there is a bug present that returns an empty string on `file-type` when used on images. You can work around this by checking the extension.

Comment: and where do i define the maxsize?

Comment: @JohannesSchütt You need to get that value from PHP or hard code into the function. You define it after the loop. Sum all the file sizes and check if the size is greater than max. If so don't allow the form to be posted.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `$_POST['file']` to `$_FILES['file']`

and try:

```
// check maximum size 
        if($_FILES['file']['size'] > $maxsize) 
         die('The file is too large');
// check file format
        elseif( !in_array(pathinfo(strtolower($_FILES['files']['name']), PATHINFO_EXTENSION),$allowedex))
         die($_FILES['files']['name'].' is not a valid format.');
```

Comment: This is actually correct. You need to use `$_FILES` and refer to the file inputs form name using `$_FILES['file']`. +1

Answer (score -1):

interesting....i prefer less lines of code...

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
<table>
<tr><td><p>your name:</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><input required="required" name="name" type="text" size="50" style="height: 30px;"></td></tr>
<tr><td><p>your mail-adress:</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><input required="required" name="mail" type="text" size="50" style="height: 30px;"></td></tr>
<tr><td><p>your document:</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><input required="required" type="file" name="file" value="" /><br /><h6 style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 2px;">max. filesize: 2 MB<br />allowed filetypes: .doc, .docx, .pdf, .rtf, .odt</h6></td></tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

php :

```
<?php
define('MB', 1048576);
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$file = $_FILES['file'];
$allowedext =  array('doc','docx' ,'pdf', 'rtf', 'odt');
$filename = $file['tmp_name'];
$ext=explode(".",$filename);
if( empty($name) || empty($mail) || empty($file) || $_FILES['file']['size'] > 2*MB || !in_array($ext[1],$allowedext) )
{
echo "check file extension or check whether all fields are filled correctly!";
exit;
}
else
{
 move_uploaded_file(name, name);
 echo "File has been uploaded successfully!";
}
?>
```

Comment: tried your code by uploading a pdf file. but i got the error message, although the file was 202 kb big

Comment: code updated! i didn't managed to see you have used $_POST for files! you should have used $_FILES for uploading files! anyway i have corrected it and test it also...

Comment: This code has numerous flaws: you are using $file['tmp_name'] for explode(), while you should use $file['name']. Also, what happened to the arguments of move_uploaded_file()? First argument should be $filename (which contains the 'tmp_name' variable) and the second one the new file name and its directory i.e. "/some/path/" . basename($file['name']) - note the use of basename() as a security measure. There are more problems, but these are the most severe... Less code is not always better